# Строка в массив js

Tags: javascript, массивы, строки

Как можно преобразовать строку вида `"[a][b][c]"` в массив, не прибегая к ручному посимвольному разбору?

Answer (score 4):

```js
console.log("[a][b][c]".match(/[^[\]]+/gi));
```

Answer (score 3):

Статья о [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from), либо [`.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split).

```js
var line = "[a][b][c][d][e]";
var arr = line.replace(/\[/g, '').replace(/\]/g, '').split('');
// Либо использовать Array.from();
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 2):

Вот ещё вариант :)

```js
const str = '[a][b][c][d]';
const arr = [...str].filter(char => char.match(/[^\[\]]/));
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно воспользоваться оператором разворота массива...  ECMA-6

```js
var str = "hello ";

var arr = [...str];

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73352/discussion-on-answer-by-air----js).

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так.

```
var str = "[a][b][c]";
var arr = str.replace(new RegExp("]", 'g'), "").split("[");
```